# count the number of strings in a 2-D pandas series

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multidimensional-array

I am trying to count the number of characters in an uneven 2-D pandas series.

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : [['a','b'],['a','c','f'],['a'], ['b','f']]}

I want to count the number of times each character is repeated.

any ideas?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is a dupe but you can use `DataFrame.explode` and value_counts, df['A'].explode().value_counts()

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html?highlight=value_c).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : [['a','b'],['a','c','f'],['a'], ['b','f']]})

df = df.explode("A")
print(df.value_counts())
```

Expected output:

```
A
a    3
b    2
f    2
c    1
```